# How to add pagination to Wordpress page template with scribus posts 2 posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

Cheers!

I'm trying to build a "references - services" relation on my Wordpress page and I try to create my own "archive - like" page. On these page I have a problem with displaying the posts with a pagination.

I have the two custom post types "reference" and "service". Both are connected with *scribus Wordpress Plugin "Posts2Posts"* and my sites should contain the following content:

**archive-reference.php:** Listing of all services that have at least one reference. But that isn't the problem. Not the normal goal of an archive page...

**reference-service-page-template.php:** Custom page template that displays all references for a service. So in that way, its the new "reference archive" filtered by service.

---

### Some code

If its relevant, thats the **p2p connection** (its working):

```
p2p_register_connection_type( array(
    'name' => 'service_to_reference',
    'from' => 'service',
    'to' => 'reference',
    'title' => array(
        'from' => __( 'Joint references', 'translation-domain' ),
        'to' => __( 'Joint Services', 'translation-domain' )
    ),
    'from_labels' => array(
        'singular_name' => __( 'Service', 'translation-domain' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search service', 'translation-domain' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No services found', 'translation-domain' ),
        'create' => __( 'Join', 'translation-domain' ),
    ),
    'to_labels' => array(
        'singular_name' => __( 'Reference', 'translation-domain' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search reference', 'translation-domain' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No references found', 'translation-domain' ),
        'create' => __( 'Join', 'translation-domain' ),
    )
) );
```

Thats the **wp_rewrite action** for the new archive "reference-service-page-template.php":

```
add_action('init', 'theme_name_reference_p2p_service_url');

function theme_name_reference_p2p_service_url() {
  $url = get_theme_option('reference-service-url');
  $page_slug = get_theme_option('reference-service-page-slug');

  global $wp, $wp_rewrite;
  $wp->add_query_var('service_single');
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule(sprintf('%s([^/]+)', $url), sprintf('index.php?pagename=%s&service_single=$matches[1]', $page_slug),'top');
}
```

With these action its posible to call the example page:

- domain.dev/references/service/web-development (working)
- domain.dev/references/service/web-development/page/2 (not working)

"references" is the real archive. "service" is the fake archive with the page template. And the last part is the service post type page slug.
This page is accessible and its displaying the references. But for me its currently not possible to display the references on multiple pages. This is the first code part of the page template:

```
get_header();

global $wp_query;

if (isset($wp_query->query['service_single'])) {

    $service_title = $wp_query->query['service_single'];
    $post = get_page_by_path($service_title, OBJECT, 'service');

    // var_dump(get_query_var('page'));

    $service_reference_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'connected_type' => 'service_to_reference',
        'connected_items' => $post,
        'nopaging' => false,
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'paged' => (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1, 

    ));

    if ( $service_reference_query->have_posts() ) {
        ...
    }

}
```

The pagination itself is working. Its displayed after all references. But when I click on the second page I still see the six references of the first page. It's kind of frustrating...

---

### The key questions

1. Is it possible to display the p2p connected posts with a pagination?
2. Is it possible to display the posts of a second wp_query with a pagination?

If you have any questions, or if you would like further information or code, please don't hesitate to contact me.

Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First bug

I found the bug in my **custom rewrite rule**.
I forgot to add the second rewrite rule for the page.

Here is my new custom rewrite action:

```
add_action('init', 'theme_name_reference_p2p_service_url');

function theme_name_reference_p2p_service_url() {
  $url = get_theme_option('reference-service-url');
  $page_slug = get_theme_option('reference-service-page-slug');

  global $wp, $wp_rewrite;
  $wp->add_query_var('service_single');
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule(sprintf('%s([^/]+)$', $url), sprintf('index.php?pagename=%s&service_single=$matches[1]', $page_slug),'top');
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule(sprintf('%s([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$', $url), sprintf('index.php?pagename=%s&service_single=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', $page_slug),'top');
}
```

Important is the `$` char at the end of the rewrite rule. It indicates that the URL stops there.

After adding the rewrite rule to the function, its important to resafe the permalink structure.

---

### Second bug

The second bug was the **query var 'page'** in the custom WP_Query args. This is the correct args array:

```
$args = array(
  'connected_type' => 'service_to_reference',
  'connected_items' => $post,
  'nopaging' => 0,
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1, 
);
```